# Kafka some of my consumers does not consume

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with 32 partition, which all of them have data in it.

But when I start multiple consumer to consume on it, only 4 consumer could get data form topic.

Metadata of the topic:

[image]

Here is the monitoring dashboard:

[image]

And here it the final statistics data:

[image]

*complementary* consumer config:

```
import "gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka"

config := kafka.ConfigMap{
        "broker.address.family": "v4", // Avoid connecting to IPv6 brokers
        "bootstrap.servers":     addr,
        "group.id":              groupID,
        "session.timeout.ms":    6000,
        "auto.offset.reset":     "earliest",
    }
```

Comment: Can you include your Kafka consumer properties?

Comment: @maitreyak the consumer config has been added to the end of question

Comment: Can you all the properties, even the implicit ones you not set. They typically get logged once the consumer starts. Also, need clarification, how many consumes do you have in your process?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the multiple consumers have unique client ids. Especially if the consumers are part of the same OS process.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially we need to make sure that all the consumers are having the same value of the property `group.id`

A unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer belongs to. This property is required if the consumer uses either the group management functionality by using `subscribe(topic)` or the Kafka-based offset management strategy.